# Artificial Neural Network R^4 to R^2 example

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Given a target function f: R^4 -> R^2, can you draw me(give me an example) an Artificial Neural Network , lets say with two layers, and 3 nodes in the hidden layer.

Now, I think I understand how an ANN works when a function is like [0,1]^5 ->[0,1], but I am not quite sure how to do an example from R4 to R2.
I am new to machine learning, and it's a little bit diffult to catch up with all this concepts.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need two neurons in the output layer. Each neuron would correspond to one dimension of your output space.

Neurons in the output layer don't need an activation function that limits their values in the [0,1] interval (e.g. the logistic function). And even if you scale your output space in the interval [0,1], don't use a sigmoid function for activation.

Although your original data is not in [0,1]^4, you should do some preprocessing to scale and shift them to have mean zero and variance 1. You must apply same preprocessing to all your examples (training and test).

This should give you something to build up on.

Comment: anyway, suppose I have drawn the example. What is the dimension of the model of this ANN ?

Comment: What dimension are you referring to? The VC dimension?

Comment: it was a question of my problem, I am not quite sure which dimension is refering to.